# How do contemporary processors differ from a pure von Neumann architecture?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, processor, von-neumann

So I never really understood the von Neumann architecture, and have started to revise it as I wasn't in school during the lessons of the CPU. Can't really get help through my teacher as they wont respond to their email.

I have learnt about the von Neumann architecture, and now I need to know how the architecture differs from a contemporary processor.

I know that contemporary processors sometime use a mixture of Harvard and von Neumann architecture by using Harvard for the communication between the control unit and caches though for cost effective reasons von Neumann is used between the main memory and cpu.

The specification point wants to know how it differs though, and I will be very thankful for any responses that might answer the question.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a better fit on [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or maybe [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider thanks, I haven't really used this site other than looking at examples of code to see how it all works. I'll take a look over there :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I may have answered my own question, the specification just wanted to know how it differs from the **pure** von Neumann architecture. It differs as contemporary processors use a mixture of architectures from Harvard and von Neumann for many reasons (mainly cost) and where speed advantages outweigh the complexity costs.

Contemporary processors use a mixture of both von Neumann and Harvard architecture, which differs from a pure von Neumann architecture by using von Neumann architecture for the main memory to the CPU and Harvard for the control unit and caches.

Comment: Generally only the L1 cache is different for instruction and data side (Harvard architecture). The L2/L3 caches are still shared and follow the Von Neumann architecture.